# Manipulating JSON data filling bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

When building a bootstrap table from a JSON file, using the method below, is there anyway to wrap that data in a  function to change the visual output to the table? For example if I was returning `status: 1` from the JSON, is there a way to show this number one as a string like `active` when it renders in the table? Or would I need to manipulate the data before it was loaded into the table with regular JavaScript, JQuery or whatever?

This is the method I would ideally like to use to fill the table, other methods aren't out of the question, this just feels like the cleanest, simplest way to fill the table.

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    url: 'data1.json',
    columns: [{
        field: 'id',
        title: 'Item ID'
    }, {
        field: 'name',
        title: 'Item Name'
    }, {
        field: 'price',
        title: 'Item Price'
    }, ]
});
```

Comment: use `formatter` option...see http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/21/. More details in docs about arguments available

Comment: Thanks that just what I'm after if you want to pop it in as the answer I can mark it as correct for future readers?

Comment: Well to be honest I have never even used that plugin and found it in the docs and examples in about 3 minutes. Suggest more thorugh reading of docs before asking questions